# Keyboard Shortcut to go to "Sent" in Google Inbox

Tags: gmail, keyboard-shortcuts, inbox-by-gmail

In Gmail, I used to be able to press <kbd>g</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> to go directly to the "Sent" emails folder.  After switching to Google Inbox, this keyboard shortcut does not seem to work anymore.

Still, Google Inbox has keyboard shortcuts for navigating to the inbox (<kbd>i</kbd>) or setting up a reminder (<kbd>t</kbd>). The lack of a shortcut for the Sent folder puzzles me. Was this keyboard left out deliberately? If that was the case, is there any way to bring this shortcut back without switching back to the original Gmail interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short answer

At this time Inbox by Gmail doesn't have a keyboard short to go to Sent.

## Alternatives

- Set a bookmark to go to https://inbox.google.com/u/0/sent
- Use a keyboard shortcut manager extension

## How to know the available keyboard shortcuts for Inbox by Gmail

From [Keyboard shortcuts for Inbox on a computer](https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/6080523?hl=en)

> Save time going through your inbox and composing emails with keyboard
>   shortcuts.
>
> See the list of keyboard shortcuts
>   1. Open Inbox on your computer.
>   2. Hold Shift and press ? on your keyboard.
>   3. You'll see a list of available keyboard shortcuts.
>   If you don't see the list of shortcuts, you'll need to turn on keyboard shortcuts.